# How to map no longer value enum member in Fluent Nhib?

Tags: enums, fluent-nhibernate

We have this region enum which has member "US"

```
[Flags]
[DataContract]
public enum Region
{
    [EnumMember]
    None = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    US = 2,

    [EnumMember]
    APAC = 4,

    [EnumMember]
    EMEA = 8,

    [EnumMember]
    AMER = 32,
}
```

We would like to retire "US" member and we will swap all usages in code to "AMER". 
But we also need to setup ClassMap so that any existing retrieved entities from DB will have to default to "AMER" (where it was saved down as "US" earlier).

How can we achieve that?  It is saved down as string in DB

Comment: Can't you just change the value in your db to "AMER"?

Comment: i coudl but then I would have to change in lots of places... was wondering if ORM layer could that translation for me

Comment: Inhouse, we use a Update-Script/Function for such cases. When a client receives a new version, its part of the update process. Maybe its possible that NHibernate can do that for you, but i don't know the way.